# Cordova loading XML and JSON files with PreloaderJS (CreateJS) doesn't work

Tags: ios, cordova, createjs, preloadjs

I'm developing an HTML5 game with CreateJS and I'm using Cordova to build for Android and iOS platforms.

The problem is that on iOS, the .xml and .json files are not loaded with PreloaderJS.

I have a xml file and I try to load it:

```
_loader = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
_loader.loadFile({src:"assets/generic/levels/landingScreen/xml/logic.xml", type:createjs.AbstractLoader.XML});
```

It works on web and on Android, but it doesn't work on iOS.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Any more details? Does it throw errors in the console? Does it stop completion? Does it just get skipped? Does it finish but have no content?

Comment: I've added listeners: _loader.addEventListener(FILE_LOADED, handleFileLoad);
        _loader.addEventListener(ERROR, handleError); and I'm getting handleError